# Is there any way to map the following object from an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to map object from an API to render method. but unable to map.

I have tried it by

```
{
  Uid : "1" ,
  value : 
  {
   "genre": "Artist" ,
   ....
  }
}
```

and its fine, its working
but i wanna try it following, as my API contains following object

```
{
  "Uid": {
    "genre": "Artist" , 
    ....
  }
}
```

whole object is as follows in firebase db

```
{
    "Uid": {
        "title": "someTitle",
        "description": "Bla Bla",
        "artistName": "Bla Bla",
        "url": "someUrl",
        "likeCount": 9,
        "time": {
            "_seconds": 1564426800,
            "_nanoseconds": 0
        },
        "genre": "someGenre"
    }
}
```

My constructor contains

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      categories: [],
      G1 : [],
      G2 : [],
      G3 : []
    }; 
}
```

Also componentdidmount follows, in for loop first object into grid G1, second into G2, 3rd into G3, 4th into G1 and so on thats why i have a for loop. The problem is instead of this.state.categories[j], there should be something else, what that is. i dont know

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("/getArtCol").then(res => {
      const key = Object.keys(res.data);
      const value = Object.values(res.data);   
      const length = this.state.categories.length

      key.forEach((element, i ) => {
        this.state.categories.push({name: element , title:Object.values(value[i])[0], price:Object.values(value[i])[1], url:Object.values(value[i])[2], likeCount:Object.values(value[i])[3], description:Object.values(value[i])[4], artistName:Object.values(value[i])[5], genre:Object.values(value[i])[6]});
      });

      let j = 0
      for(let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        //this.state.paintingKeys.push({name: element , url:value[i]});
        this.state.G1.push(this.state.categories[j])
        j++
        if  (j===length){
          break;
        }                                           
        this.state.G2.push(this.state.categories[j])
        j++
        if  (j===length){
          break;
        }
        this.state.G3.push(this.state.categories[j])
        j++
        if  (j===length){
          break;
        }
      };
      this.setState({ });    
     console.log(res.data)
     //console.log(this.state.G1)
     //console.log(this.state.G2)
     //console.log(this.state.G3)    
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    })

  }
```

I expect map of it first object into grid G1, second into G2, 3rd into G3, 4th into G1 and so on

```
  render(){ 
    const { classes } = this.props;
    let galleryMapped1 = this.state.G1 ? (this.state.G1.map(category=>(            
      <div>
        <h6>{category.Uid.title}</h6>
        <h4>{category.Uid.price}</h4>
        <h4 >{category.Uid.genre}</h4>
        <h4 >{category.Uid.artistName}</h4>
        <h4>{category.Uid.description}</h4>
        <h4>{category.Uid.likeCount}</h4>
      </div>
    ))) : (<p>Sorry, data not fetched</p>)

    let galleryMapped2 = this.state.G2 ? (this.state.G2.map(category=>(      
      <div>
      <h6>{category.Uid.title}</h6>
      <h4>{category.Uid.price}</h4>
      <h4 >{category.Uid.genre}</h4>
      <h4 >{category.Uid.artistName}</h4>
      <h4>{category.Uid.description}</h4>
      <h4>{category.Uid.likeCount}</h4>
    </div>
    ))) : (<p>Sorry, data not fetched</p>)

    let galleryMapped3 = this.state.G3 ? (this.state.G3.map(category=>(    
      <div>
      <h6>{category.Uid.title}</h6>
      <h4>{category.Uid.price}</h4>
      <h4 >{category.Uid.genre}</h4>
      <h4 >{category.Uid.artistName}</h4>
      <h4>{category.Uid.description}</h4>
      <h4>{category.Uid.likeCount}</h4>
    </div>
    ))) : (<p>Sorry, data not fetched</p>)

    return (
      <div>
        {galleryMapped1}   
        {galleryMapped2}
        {galleryMapped3}
      </div>   

    );   
  }
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried in your render method? What's not working? Is there an error?

Comment: what is the expected output

Comment: Unless this will be an object with multiple values of the same shape then any kind of mapping over the key-value pairs is not for you, just render the object fields directly.

Comment: @skovy, actually the story is, i'm trying to fetch the same object from an API through componentdidmount, I wanna just put the objects into grids that are vertically aligned like following this.state.grid1.push(this.state.categories) where categories contains objects.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want

```
 Object.keys(YourObject).map();
```

and if it's not please add more description and paste your render method here

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change what you are mapping since the two objects are not the same format:

For the first object, the members are obj.Uid and obj.value, then obj.value has obj.value.genre, etc...

But the second object is formatted differently, it has only one member, obj.Uid, which is an object with more members: obj.Uid.title, obj.Uid.description.

So if you want to map the fields title, description, etc... then you need reference obj.Uid, not just obj, and definitely not obj.value since that is not a member of the second object.

Comment: obj.Uid is fine when i have that object in my state, but in my case i am fetching that object from an API through componentdidmount life cycle method. I wanna just put the objects into grids that are vertically aligned like following this.state.grid1.push(this.state.categories) where categories contains objects.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is a collection of same-shaped objects keyed by some uuid. `Object.values` returns an array of the values that can then be iterated/mapped/reduced over, while `Object.entries` returns an array of the key-value tuples.

In this example I use the entries method and map over the array extracting the uid key and three properties from the object and construct, mapping these values to a string and printing it out at the end. Just want to illustrate the mutations of the mapped values can be anything.

```js
const dataObject = {
    "1234567890": {
        "title": "someTitle",
        "description": "Bla Bla",
        "artistName": "Bla Bla",
        "url": "someUrl",
        "likeCount": 9,
        "time": {
            "_seconds": 1564426800,
            "_nanoseconds": 0
        },
        "genre": "someGenre"
    },
    "9876543210": {
        "title": "someOtherTitle",
        "description": "Bla Bla Bla",
        "artistName": "Bla Bla Bla",
        "url": "someUrl",
        "likeCount": 2,
        "time": {
            "_seconds": 1564426900,
            "_nanoseconds": 0
        },
        "genre": "someOtherGenre"
    },
    "5432109876": {
        "title": "someOtherOtherTitle",
        "description": "Bla Bla, oops",
        "artistName": "Bla Bla, oops",
        "url": "someUrl",
        "likeCount": 1337,
        "time": {
            "_seconds": 1564423800,
            "_nanoseconds": 0
        },
        "genre": "someOtherCoolGenre"
    },
};

const mappedData = Object.entries(dataObject)
  .map(([uid, { genre, likeCount, title }]) => {
    return `${title.toUpperCase()} (liked ${likeCount} times) [uid: ${uid}] <${genre}>`;
  });

console.log(mappedData);
```

If you are fetching data through an async API request then your component would look similar to below. Async requests typically return promises, so you can process the resolved promise.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    data: null,
    error: null,
    isLoading: true,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    asyncApiRequest(...)
      .then(response => {
        // This will be specific to the shape of the API response!!
        this.setState({ data: response.data.myDataArray });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error });
      });
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }

  function renderData(data) {
    return Object.entries(data)
      .map((uid, { description, genre, title }) => (
        <div>
          <h1>{title} ({uid})</h1>
          <dl>
            <dt>Genre</dt>
            <dd>{genre}</dd>
            <dt>Description</dt>
            <dd>{description}</dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      ));
  }

  render() {
    const { data, error, isLoading } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) return <LoadingSpinner />;

    if (error) {
      return (
        <div>There was an error fetching data: ${error}</div>
      );
    }

    return data.length ?
      renderData(data)
    : (
      <div>No data to display</div>
    );
  }
}
```

[edit: to address sorting into three bins "G1", "G2", and "G3"]

In order to sort into three grid bins then what you have is close, but you want to iterate through your data once and selectively push a result into bin 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ... I numbered the bins from 0 as we can use modular division with the index to compute which bin an element should go into. We can do this as it seems there are no other dependencies for bin number other than the original order.

```
componentDidMount(){
  axios.get("/getArtCol").then(res => {
    const dataEntries = Object.entries(res.data);

    const G1 = [];
    const G2 = [];
    const G3 = [];

    // Map to a categories array [{ name: key, title, genre, ...}, ...]
    const categories = dataEntries.map(([key, element]) => ({
        name: key,
        ...element
      });

    // Sort into 1 of 3 grid "bins"
    for(let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      if (i % 3 === 0) {
        G1.push(categories[i]);
      }
      if (i % 3 === 1) {
        G2.push(categories[i]);
      }
      if (i % 3 === 2) {
        G3.push(categories[i]);
      }
    };

    this.setState({
      categories,
      G1,
      G2,
      G3,
    });        
  }).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
  });
}
```

It doesn't seem you ever use categories outside this computation, so a more succinct version:

```
componentDidMount(){
  axios.get("/getArtCol")
    .then(res => {
      const dataEntries = Object.entries(res.data);

      // Map to a categories array [{ name: key, title, genre, ...}, ...]
      // then reduce directly into the three grid bins
      const grids = dataEntries.map(([key, element], i ) => ({
          name: key,
          ...element
        })
        .reduce(({G1, G2, G3}, category, i) => {
            if (i % 3 === 0) {
              G1.push(category);
            }
            if (i % 3 === 1) {
              G1.push(category);
            }
            if (i % 3 === 2) {
              G1.push(category);
            }

            return {G1, G2, G3};
          },
          { G1: [], G2: [], G3: []}
        );

      this.setState(grids);        
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    });
  }
```

Comment: and if i am fetching the exact same from an API through componentdidmount method, what should be my code looks like?

Comment: @mudassirijaz added more to answer.

Comment: for(let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        //this.state.paintingKeys.push({name: element , url:value[i]});
        this.state.G1.push(this.state.categories[j])
        j++
        if  (j===length){
          break;
        }                                           
        this.state.G2.push(this.state.categories[j])
        j++
        if  (j===length){
          break;
        }
        this.state.G3.push(this.state.categories[j])
        j++
        if  (j===length){
          break;
        }
      };

Comment: i am unable to make logic where i am pushing this.state.categories into G1, G2 and G3

Comment: What are `i`, `j`, `length`, `paintingKeys`, `G1`, `G2`, `G3`, and `categories`? These seem unrelated to, or at least not mentioned by, your original question. Can you update your question to include everything that explains what these variables represent and why you need them? Can you also add some expected result for what you want?

Comment: Hi @Drew Reese, my next query is, when user clicks on an object (containing title etc, i have designed it using Cards). It should get Id of that clicked object and pops that into new page. I will route that but i am unable to get Id of that object on clickHandler because these objects are in G1, G2 or may be in G3.

Comment: @mudassirijaz Can you either update your code here or post all that up in a separate question? The answer will really depend on how you handle routing within your app and any other work that needs to be done before routing. The general gist for it will be something like: on the div/element containing the onClick `onClick={() => history.push(\`/path/path2/${uid}\`)}`, but this assumes you are using something like `react-router-dom`. You can factor that callback out, but remember to pass the `uid` to it so it knows which id to use for building the route.